# Is it ideal to have more than one phantomjs worker spawned from node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

We are using phantomjs to take screenshots of various webpages and the url is sent by clients in a node.js server which in turn spawns phantomjs to take the screenshot and sends the base64 image. Is it ideal to spawn more than one phantomjs worker to do this job? If there are 5 client requests there would be 5 spawned processes. I've limited the number to 5 irrespective of the number of client requests. But is 5 spawned processes also pushing it on a server?

Comment: You could write a PhantomJS worker script with the webserver module which can handle 10 simultaneous requests and then you can write a node.js script that spawns PhantomJS processes if needed and terminates if not. Then you can benchmark with different allowed requests per PhantomJS process to find the sweet spot for CPU/memory/duration. You really should benchmark it yourself and the result will probably depend on the version you used and the specific websites you navigate to. Don't forget to post an answer when you did that and have produced some results.

Comment: Thanks @ArtjomB. I would definitely post the results once I run benchmark them.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: **Yes**, it is completely fine to have more than one PhantomJS worker running. For my master thesis, I crawled more than one million websites and used multiple workers (also spawned from Node.js).

To check how many workers are viable for your system, you can use the tools `nload` and `htop` (for linux). `nload` shows you the network usage and `htop` shows you the usage of memory and CPU. Just fire up some PhantomJS instances to crawl some pages and monitor the usage of the resources to check for the limit.

You also might want to check out the [phantomjs-pool](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/phantomjs-pool) library (disclaimer: I am the author) as it will help you to queue the jobs and also takes care of various error possibilities and timeouts.

Some findings from the crawling I did:

- CPU: You can run about 4 workers per CPU core.
- Memory: Each workers needs between 50 and 400 MB depending on your setup (keep in mind the [memory leaks](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11390)).
- Throughput: A worker that constantly accesses websites needs a throughput of about 2 MBit/s.
- Duration: The time it takes to crawl a website heavily depends on what you are crawling. In my setup, the crawling of a single website took between 10 and 15 seconds on average depending on which list was crawled.

To give an example: In my setup I was limited to a throughput of 8 MBit/s, which led to the usage of four workers.

All of these values are the results of my crawling process and might heavily vary for different websites of course.